# Setting a static member of a variable class in php

Tags: php, class, static, member

I'm trying to add a static member to each of my classes that contains the default database connection that they should use when instantiated.  Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
<?php //other classes extend Generic
class Generic {
    public static $defaultDatabase;
    public $db;

    function __construct (&$pDatabase = null){
        if ($pDatabase!==null)
            $this->db = &$pDatabase;
        else
            $this->db = &$defaultDatabase;
    }   
}
?>


<?php
include_once("/classes/class.Database.php");
$db = new Database ("localhost", "username", "password", "TestDatabase");

$classes = array("Generic", "Member");
foreach ($classes as $class){
    include_once("/classes/class.$class.php");
    $class::defaultDatabase = &$db;//throws error here, unexpected "="
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to do this, or do I have to set the defaultDatabase for each class individually?  I'm using php 5.3, which I understand should support something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
 $class::defaultDatabase = &$db
```

You should add $ before defaultDatabase, since static properties are accessed via

`ClassName::$staticProperty`

Unlike the others which are accessed via

`$class->property;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `self::$propertyName` to access [static properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

```
function __construct (&$pDatabase = null){
    if ($pDatabase!==null)
        $this->db = &$pDatabase;
    else
        $this->db = self::$defaultDatabase;
}
```

Also note, that using the reference operator `&$var` is meaningless if `$var` is an object. This is because all objects in PHP are actually references.

Comment: Good to know, but not quite the answer I needed.  Thanks, though.